# Archiving Bacula Volumes

Tags: linux, backup, bacula

I am currently working on getting my bacula situation straighted out and have a bunch of full volumes within a file device. I don't want to just destroy the backups but do want to free up space. What is the proper way to move a volume off of the server, but still have everything retained in that catalog for the normal retention periods?

After I have done this my plan is to create new volumes in the series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a [copy job](http://www.bacula.org/manuals/en/concepts/concepts/Migration_Copy.html). It will purge catalog entries of the first (backup) job though.

Comment: This *seems* kind of off to me... I can't just move the volumes themselves?

Comment: Well you could just move the archives with their bootstrap files to another location. But wouldn't that kind of "corrupt" the catalog?

Comment: Well isn't this just like ejecting a tape? I just want to "eject" it from the backup device and put it over on the shelf :-P